# postgres function update large table and deletion performance

Tags: postgresql, performance, cpu-usage, postgresql-9.3

postgres version: 9.3
postgres.conf: all default configurations

I have 2 tables, A and B,both have 1 million rows.
There is a postgres function that will execute every 2 seconds, it will update Table A where ids in an array(array size = 20), and then delete the rows in Table B.
DB function shows as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function (ids NUMERIC[])
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  UPDATE A a
  SET status = 'begin', end_time = (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
  WHERE a.id = ANY (ids);

  DELETE FROM B b
  WHERE b.aid = ANY (ids)
    AND b.status = 'end';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Analysis shows as below:

```
explain(ANALYZE,BUFFERS,VERBOSE) select test_function('{2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}');
```

### QUERY PLAN

```
Result  (cost=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=14030.435..14030.436 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: test_function('{2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}'::numeric[])
   Buffers: shared hit=24297 read=26137 dirtied=20
 Total runtime: 14030.444 ms
(4 rows)
```

**My Question is:**

1. In the production environment, why this function need to execute at most 7 seconds before success;
2. When this function is executing, this process will eats up to 60%. --> This is the key problem

**EDIT:**
Analyze each single sql:

```
explain(ANALYZE,VERBOSE,BUFFERS) UPDATE A a SET status = 'begin', 
end_time = (now()) WHERE a.id = ANY 
('{2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}');

                                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                                               

 Update on public.A a  (cost=0.45..99.31 rows=20 width=143) (actual time=1.206..1.206 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=206 read=27 dirtied=30
   ->  Index Scan using A_pkey on public.a a  (cost=0.45..99.31 rows=20 width=143) (actual time=0.019..0.116 rows=19 loops=1)
         Output: id, start_time, now(), 'begin'::character varying(255), xxxx... ctid
         Index Cond: (t.id = ANY('{2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}'::integer[]))
         Buffers: shared hit=75 read=11
 Trigger test_trigger: time=5227.111 calls=1
 Total runtime: 5228.357 ms
(8 rows)
```

```
 explain(ANALYZE,BUFFERS,VERBOSE) DELETE FROM 
B b WHERE tq.aid = ANY 
('{2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}');
                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                                
 Delete on B b  (cost=0.00..1239.11 rows=20 width=6) (actual time=6.013..6.013 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=448
   ->  Seq Scan on B b (cost=0.00..1239.11 rows=20 width=6) (actual time=6.011..6.011 rows=0 loops=1)
         Output: ctid
         Filter: (b.aid = ANY ('{2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}'::bigint[]))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 21743
         Buffers: shared hit=448
 Total runtime: 6.029 ms
(8 rows)
```

**CPU usage**

Before calling: 
[image]

Afer frequently operations:
[image]

Comment: Why are you using an [unsupported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) version?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added the explain result above. would you please help to check again?

Comment: The time for the UPDATE statement is completely dominated by your `test_trigger` you need to investigate what that does. Without it, the update takes less than 2 milliseconds. The DELETE statement only takes 6 milliseconds anyway. So without the trigger the whole function would run in under 10 milliseconds

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I only have an index on a(id), b(id), and a.id is a foreigh key to table b

Comment: Given that your trigger is the problem, the indexes are irrelevant (because the statements themselves very fast)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is it related to data mount? Table A has more than 1 million rows and this table will be scanned every 2 seconds even it has an index on id.

Comment: Again: it's your **trigger** (`test_trigger`) which slows down your function. Each statement itself is really fast. The UPDATE needs `0.0012` seconds (1.2ms) and the DELETE needs `0.006` seconds (6ms). But as you have not shown us what that trigger does you created, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hi, sorry to bother again. I updated the post by adding some system analysis. Also I have optimized by db functions with batch update, after that  it's total runtime is: 688.508 ms. I analyzed each sql inside the function but their total runtime is only 1.8ms. I still don't know what's happened for the remained 600+ms ┑(￣Д ￣)┍

Comment: **Again**:  it's your **trigger** that causes this problem. Until you show us what that `test_trigger` does, this is impossible to answer